# Redirect to a react route using phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, reactjs, react-router

I'm working with a react.js project and convert it into a mobile application, that part is ok, the idea is that the app must receive push notifications, once the user clicks the notification, it must change the react route, I've been trying this code but had not success the app doesn't change the route once the user clicks the notification, I had success getting the react-router instance, but i don't know how to use it properly to go to the desired route.

```
 var app = {
    initialize: function() {
      this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
      var mmjUser=localStorage.getItem("mmj-user");
      if (mmjUser !== null) {
        var push = PushNotification.init({
         "android": {
           "senderID": "491359499412",
           "forceShow": 'true'
         },
         "ios": {
          "alert": "true",
          "badge": "true",
          "sound": "true",
          "senderID": "491359499412"},
          "windows": {}
        });

        push.on('registration', function(data) {
         console.log("registration event");
      });

        push.on('notification', function(data) {
         console.log("notification event");
         console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
         var reactRouter=require('react-router');
         reactRouter.HistoryLocation.replace('/waiting');

         push.finish(function () {
           console.log('finish successfully called');
         });
       });

        push.on('error', function(e) {
         console.log("push error");
       });
      }

    }
  };

  app.initialize();
```

this is the reactRouter object that i'm getting

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try `reactRouter.History.push('/waiting');`

Comment: I'm getting `Error in Success callbackId: PushNotification241661182 : TypeError: undefined is not a function    cordova.js:310`

Comment: sorry it should be `reactRouter.browserHistory.push('/waiting');`
Did it help?

Comment: ´TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined cordova.js:310´ if it helps, my react-router version is 0.13.3